# Why do I get this PyPy output when checking the installation version?

Tags: python, pypy

I have downloaded the latest version of PyPy and am trying to run some Python script unsuccessfully. When I check the version using "pypy3 -v", I get the following response. What does this mean please?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pypy3 -v
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\\lib-python\\3\\encodings\\__pycache__\\__init__.pypy3-72.pyc'
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\__pycache__\codecs.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\codecs.py
# code object from 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\\lib-python\\3\\__pycache__\\codecs.pypy3-72.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x011b4a30>
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\aliases.py
# code object from 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\\lib-python\\3\\encodings\\__pycache__\\aliases.pypy3-72.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x011d5c70>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x011b4890>
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\utf_8.py
# code object from 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\\lib-python\\3\\encodings\\__pycache__\\utf_8.pypy3-72.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x011d5c90>
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\latin_1.py
# code object from 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\\lib-python\\3\\encodings\\__pycache__\\latin_1.pypy3-72.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x011d5cb0>
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__pycache__\mbcs.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\mbcs.py
# code object from 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\\lib-python\\3\\encodings\\__pycache__\\mbcs.pypy3-72.pyc'
import 'encodings.mbcs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x011f2770>
# C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\__pycache__\cp850.pypy3-72.pyc matches C:\pypy3.6-v7.2.0rc1-win32\lib-python\3\encodings\cp850.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PyPy, like on CPython, the '-v' option enables verbose imports, where the interpreter prints out some information about every module it imports.

If you want to check the interpreter version, use '-V' or '--version'.